# JPanel repaint() method issues

Tags: java, swing, graphics

I am using a JPanel and JFrame class to create simple graphics in a window and have found a rather odd problem. My current setup is as such:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class MyFrame extends JFrame{

    public MyFrame() {
        super("App Schmapp!");
        this.setSize(new java.awt.Dimension(500, 500));
        this.setMinimumSize(this.getSize());
        this.setMaximumSize(this.getSize());
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyPanel c = new MyPanel();
        MyFrame a = new MyFrame();
        a.add(c);
        c.repaint();

    }

}
```

Above is obviously my JFrame class and below is my JPanel class

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class MyPanel extends JPanel {

    public void paintComponent(Graphics G) {
        super.paintComponent(G);
        Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) G;
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.fillRect(50, 50, 50, 50);
    }

}
```

My hope would be that this would work, however when I run this code a blank window pops up with no graphics. The part I don't understand is that if I changed the dimensions of the JFrame to something like 7000 by 10000 it works fine... please help?

Comment: No need to call `repaint()` here. Simply call `setVisible(true)` on the JFrame **after** adding all components. A common problem.

Comment: So delete the line `c.repaint();` and in its place move `a.setVisible(true);`

Answer (score 0):

Replace `c.repaint();` to:

```
a.pack();
a.setVisible(true);
```

It should show red square as you wish.